# having default arguments for passed references in C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, default-parameters

I have a number of functions that take references to `typedef`'d data types, as below:

```
typedef std::map<string, string> dict;

union ret_t{
    int i;
    long l;
    double d;
};

ret_t func1(char* bytes, dict &d){
    //blah blah
}
ret_t func2(char* bytes, dict &d){
    //blah blah 2
}
```

I also have a map of handler functions, using `boost::function` as defined below:

```
std::map <int, boost::function< ret_t (char*, dict) > > handlers;
```

I defined this so that, with the >100 handler functions that I am using, I can simply read a key and call `handlers[key](bytes, d);` and have my function execute, only required 3 if/elses for my different data types (knowing the data type i need is another issue I won't get into.  It's irrelevant to the question).  This works as expected.

My issue is that a small number of the functions do not utilize the dictionary, and would be useful in a context outside the handlers (for instance, a function that ready a stream of bytes and converts it to a long int).  In order to call this function from a context in which I do not have a dict predefined, I either have to create a useless dict that is never used:

```
dict d;
func1(bytes, d);
```

Or I have to pverride the function:

```
//previous definition

ret_t func1(char* bytes){
    //same blah blah as before
}
```

When I attempt to define it with a default argument, such as `NULL` or an empty dict, I get a compiler error:

```
default argument for 'dict& d' has type 'dict {aka std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >}'
```

Is there a way to do what I want, without having to completely rewrite my code to pass pointers around instead of references?

Comment: If you wanted it to be optional, pointers would be an option, as would `boost::optional`, though I'm not sure how well it works with references, as that's what pointers are for. If you don't change `dict`, you can do `const dict & = {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those functions that don't take a dictionary, create two versions. Have one that doesn't take a dictionary as a parameter and one that does but just calls the other without the dictionary. Use the former for all direct calls and the latter for dispatching like other functions that take a dictionary.